# Was my SSD wiped?

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, secure-erase

I have a MacBook Pro Retina mid 2013,

as I intend to pass it, I used a bootable Ubuntu so I could make a ATA Secure erase.

As the disk was "not enabled" and "frozen" I had to put it to sleep by closing the lid and opening again.

When I got to run the command

```
hdparm --user-master u --security-erase password /dev/sdaX
```

It was fast, when I say fast, I mean milliseconds. I think that it took 100 ms

Is it possible that the firmware from the disk only erased the encryption keys?

When I opened GParted, the 250GB disk appeared greyed out, meaning no partitions were found. I though this was a good sign that something happened to the disk.

But I got suspicious, so I ran the commands all over again, except the last one. Opted out to use the enhanced secure erase command this time to see if the outcome would be different.

And it was, I got a secure erase that took a bit more, like 380ms

Still , is a third of a second. Same thing happened, the computer was not able to boot, this time I partitioned with Partition Tools from Mac.

Prior to this I had encrypted with filevault the disk, but my worries lie on the old files I erased before encryption.

So I wasn't happy , and I ran something that I thought it wasn't possible, I did a wipe on the disk by passing 3 times the full disk, I did this twice. How? Booted the mac, entered in recovery mode, opened the disk tools, and voila, even being an SSD it gave me that option. It took about 40 minutes to wipe out the disk with this tool.

And I did 3 installations of the operating system on the meanwhile.

I am worried about 2 or 3 small files, are the chances of recovering them that high after all this?

Comment: Wiping only the encryption keys should be entirely sufficient to prevent any chance of data recovery. What reason do you have to believe otherwise?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton I've read that normally hdparm secure erase takes seconds, i got a bit paranoid because with me it took less than a second. Later on, i found out that some SSDs have encryption keys, and deleting them is enough to secure the data. So this SSD could make use of that key encryption right?

Comment: Erasing keys - Super fast. Erasing partition table - few seconds. Erasing all cells, slowwww process. When you talk about secure erase you usually are talking about a safe method of the latter as you dont want data to be "hidden away" from your wiper by sector re-allocations that happened while wear levelling. In any case, if in doubt, DBAN.

Comment: @Linef4ult So, considering the fast it was to run the commands, i can assume that hdparm interacted with the firmware from the SSD and this last one assumed that erasing the keys would be enough? It is not a life or death situation, but i would  like to be sure that in the middle of 80GB of data it will be hard to recover a few photos (2 or 3). Of course nothing is guaranteed but to recover these 2 files would be at least a pain in the ass, right?

Comment: @Souza in real world tests even one pass of writing random bits to disks makes it nigh on impossible to get anything useful back. After three passes its goooooone. If you've nuked the keys and done a wipe over the full disk with the recovery environment only the feds could get anything back, and it'd take forever for them to do it. You're fine.

Comment: If the drive was actually encrypted, wiping the encryption keys is sufficient unless your adversary is the NSA, and quite probably even then.

Comment: @Linef4ult Thank you for the information, i think that doing the passes on the SSD was sufficient to stress it in physical terms but it's ok, doesn't matter. Why does Apple deny the erasing tools while inside the Mac OS but enables it while on recovery mode? Weird.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton As i mentioned, i only encrypted the disk, prior to deletion of the specified files. So i believe file vault doesn't encrypt the whole disk but the used part of it? Not sure. 
Anyway, i've used the MacBook Disk Tools "Erase Free Space" after encryption.